# System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression of type 'Constant'. Did you miss the member access prefix in the expression?

Tags: c#, .net, reactiveui

I am receiving the following exception within a ReactiveUI based ViewModel...

> System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression of type
> 'Constant'. Did you miss the member access prefix in the expression?

The error occurs within the constructor of the **ValidationEditorDocumentViewModel**, within an observable pipeline that is designed to monitor changes on a property (**SelectedValidatorClientViewModel**) within another Reactive ViewModel (**ValidationEditorViewModel**).

What I am trying to do is that anytime the ValidationEditorViewModel.SelectedValidatorClientViewModel property were to change, then set the **SelectedValidator** on another ViewModel (**RuleEditorViewModel**).

```
using NextWare.ProductPortalUI.RXViewModels.RXViewModels.ValidationEditor;
using ReactiveUI;
using System;

namespace NextWare.ProductPortalUI.RXViewModels.ValidationEditor
{
    public sealed partial class ValidationEditorDocumentViewModel: ReactiveObject 
    {
 
        private ValidatorEditorViewModel _validationEditorViewModel;
        private RuleEditorViewModel _ruleEditorViewModel;
      
        public ValidationEditorDocumentViewModel() 
        {
            var setValidatorRuleSet = this.WhenAnyValue(x => ValidationEditorViewModel.SelectedValidatorClientViewModel)
                .Subscribe(_ => SetValidatorOnRuleSet());
        }

        private void SetValidatorOnRuleSet()
        {
            if(RuleEditorViewModel != null)
            {
                RuleEditorViewModel.SelectedValidator = _validationEditorViewModel.SelectedValidatorClientViewModel.Validator;
            }
        }

        public ValidatorEditorViewModel ValidationEditorViewModel
        {
            get => _validationEditorViewModel;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _validationEditorViewModel, value, nameof(ValidationEditorViewModel));
        }
 
    }
}
```

This is the ViewModel that is referenced ...

```
using NextWare.Domain.ValidationServices.Validator.ClientViewModels;
using NextWare.ProductPortalUI.SharedComponents.DomainMetaExplorer.Models;
using ReactiveUI;
using Splat;
using System;
 

namespace NextWare.ProductPortalUI.RXViewModels.RXViewModels.ValidationEditor
{
    public sealed partial class ValidatorEditorViewModel : ReactiveObject 
    {
        private ValidatorsClientViewModel _validatorsClientViewModel; // Contructor Injected Domain-based ViewModel
        private ValidatorClientViewModel _selectedValidatorClientViewModel;
        private Guid _selectedDomainElementModelReferenceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        private TreeNode _selectedMetaExplorerTreeNode;

        public ValidatorEditorViewModel(ValidatorsClientViewModel validatorsClientViewModel = null)
        {
            _validatorsClientViewModel = validatorsClientViewModel ?? Locator.Current.GetService<ValidatorsClientViewModel>();
            
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedValidatorClientViewModel)
                          .Subscribe(_ => SetValidator());

            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedMetaExplorerTreeNode)  // Happens only once at startup
                        .Subscribe(_ => SetValidator());
            
        }

        private void SetValidator()
        {
            if(SelectedValidatorClientViewModel != null && SelectedMetaExplorerTreeNode != null)
            {
                SelectedValidatorClientViewModel.Validator.DomainElementName = SelectedMetaExplorerTreeNode.ModelMetaData.Name;
                SelectedValidatorClientViewModel.Validator.DomainElementNameSpace = SelectedMetaExplorerTreeNode.ModelMetaData.FqViewModelName;
                SelectedValidatorClientViewModel.Validator.DomainElementModelReferenceId = SelectedMetaExplorerTreeNode.ModelMetaData.ModelReferenceId;
                SelectedValidatorClientViewModel.Validator.AggregateRootModelReferenceId = SelectedMetaExplorerTreeNode.ParentModelMetaData.ModelReferenceId;
            }
        }

        public ValidatorsClientViewModel ValidatorsClientViewModel
        {
            get => _validatorsClientViewModel;
            private set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _validatorsClientViewModel, value, nameof(ValidatorsClientViewModel));
        }
              
        public ValidatorClientViewModel SelectedValidatorClientViewModel
        {
            get => _selectedValidatorClientViewModel;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedValidatorClientViewModel, value, nameof(SelectedValidatorClientViewModel));
        }
        public TreeNode SelectedMetaExplorerTreeNode
        {
            get => _selectedMetaExplorerTreeNode;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedMetaExplorerTreeNode, value, nameof(SelectedMetaExplorerTreeNode));
        }
    }
}
```

From documentation, WhenAnyValue extracts the value from IObservableChanged<TSender, TValue> and so as I understand it, there would only be a tick through if ValidationEditorViewModel was not null, no matter if SelectedValidatorClientViewModel were null or not.

I am confused as to why this exception is being thrown.

Comment: What happens if you change WhenAnyValue(x => Foo) to WhenAnyValue(x => x.Foo)?

Comment: Thank you Anthony, it was the lack of x. the was the issue.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned By Anthony in the comments

Change

```cs
var setValidatorRuleSet = this.WhenAnyValue(x => ValidationEditorViewModel.SelectedValidatorClientViewModel)
                .Subscribe(_ => SetValidatorOnRuleSet());
```

to

```cs
var setValidatorRuleSet = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ValidationEditorViewModel.SelectedValidatorClientViewModel)
                .Subscribe(_ => SetValidatorOnRuleSet());
```

With the additional `x` before `ValidationEditorViewModel`.

WhenAnyValue relies on you having a lambda from 'x' to your property.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the lack of the x that was the root cause for my issue.